# Site com objetos Responsivos!

Tags: css, bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Estou desenvolvendo um site em `BootStrap`! Ele está indo muito bem em questão de ser `Responsivo`.

Só que, o Background está funcionando como planejado somente em PC's, já nos `smartphones` ele até fica legal, mas ao arrastar a pagina o `background` meio que desce, mas bem em baixo, mais ou menos uns 10 ou 20 pixels fica branco!

Pergunta: Como eu faço para resolver isso?

Eu tentei usar:

```
@media (min-width: 400px) {
    body {

        background-color: #ff0080;
    }
}
```

Código do BODY:

```
    body {
        background-image: url ( "http://fullhdpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Amazing-Clash-Royale-Wallpaper.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cobertura;
 -moz-background-size: cobertura;
 -o-background-size: cobertura;
 background-size: cobertura;
    }
```

Mas, sempre que diminuo a tela, o `CSS` todo sai e só fica o `background`!

Pergunta: Como fazer para evitar isso, só alterar o que está dentro do `@media` e o resto ser original?

Se quiserem faço um JsFiddle!

Comment: Poste o link ou um código que mostre o problema acontecendo. Assim conseguimos analisar e te ajudar.

Comment: Antes de fechar a tag body, tenta colocar uma div clearfix para preencher todo o documento. Se possível insira o código no Jsfiddle como disse.

Comment: poe margin:0 0 0 0; no seu body q resolve e padding:0 0 0 0; tbm

Comment: ok mas tarde faço isso

Comment: @JasarOrion poderia me explicar para que serve o margin e o padding no body?

Comment: o margin é para afastar o body das laterais e o padding serve para afastar o conteudo interno do body para longe dele.

Comment: acesse isso aqui http://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-os-atributos-css-margin-e-padding/27969

Comment: no jsfiddle não da esse problema

Comment: @JasarOrion pronto, não deu em nada, quero que no smartphone o background fique bem fixo, e quero alterar algumas classes por tamanho! como inputs etc

Comment: uma demo do site: http://plantao-clashers.esy.es

Comment: basta vc fazer uma media query para cada tamanho o chrome tem uma extenção que sumila os tamanhos dos devices instala ela

Comment: Sempre que faço isso o css todo desaparece e fica só que tá no media

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entendi sua dúvida apesar de não ter ficado muito clara, fica um pouco difícil supor o problema sem analisar quando se trata de `css`, muita coisa pode estar acontecendo em seu código, como está declarando as regras desse background? Já tentou usar `background-size: cover`?
Existe uma ótima lib js pra trabalhar com imagens e videos em backgrounds, chamada **[Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)**, se nada disso resolver, volte aqui com mais detalhes de sua dúvida, que eu tento ajudar

Comment: sim cara vou já colocar o css do body!

Comment: Cara valeu mesmo funcionou perfeitamente esse plugin ai!